# Golang image/gif EncodeAll have many black dots

Tags: image, go, gif

I have many png images and want encode them to a gif animation.

These png images dont have any black dots ,but the gif result have many dots.

```
    g := new(gif.GIF)
    frames := len(images)
    g.Image = make([]*image.Paletted, frames)
    g.Delay = make([]int, frames)
    eg := errgroup.Group{}
    var cl color.Palette = palette.Plan9
    for k, img := range images {
        img := img
        k := k
        eg.Go(func() error {
            Paletted := image.NewPaletted(img.Bounds(), cl)
            draw.FloydSteinberg.Draw(Paletted, img.Bounds(), img, image.Point{})
            g.Image[k] = Paletted
            g.Delay[k] = deply
            return nil
        })
    }
    if err := eg.Wait(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := gif.EncodeAll(&buf, g)
```

origin png:
[image: origin png]

with num:
[image]

my png info:

> File Type                       : PNG
> File Type Extension             : png
> MIME Type                       : image/png
> Bit Depth                       : 8
> Color Type                      : RGB with Alpha
> Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
> Filter                          : Adaptive
> Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
> SRGB Rendering                  : Perceptual
> Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
> Color Space                     : sRGB

gif with black dots:
[image: gif with black dots]

used palgen.Generate(img, 256):

[image: palgen.Generate(img, 256)]

Answer (score 2):

GIF uses a 256 color palette, whereas PNG typically is RGBA with at least 8 bits per color channel (and alpha). In your incomplete example code you use the predefined [`palette.Plan9`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.2:src/image/color/palette/palette.go;l=23) color palette. Picking at least the most dominant color in the origin PNG shows it's the RGB color `#f08740`. But there is no matching color in the `Plan9` palette, so `FloydSteinberg` will have to dither using "nearest" colors from the `Plan9` palette. This obviously doesn't work well.

You need to use an adapted palette to avoid dithering either at all or at least minimize it. As you are giving a non-minimal and incomplete example, I had to roll a minimal example myself that creates a custom palette for the GIF based on the only PNG source given (and please, do upload *separate* images next time, don't put everything into a single image, it makes things really inconvenient).

A quick google search reveals the Go module [`github.com/xyproto/palgen`](https://github.com/xyproto/palgen) that does create a custom `color.Palette` based on an input image and with the specified numbers of colors; this module seems to be actively maintained and I had immediate success in using it:

```golang
img, _, err := image.Decode(f)
pal, err := palgen.Generate(img, 256)
```

The full example that produces for me a suitable GIF (`gif.gif`) without dithering, given a source PNG in `source.png`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/draw"
    "image/gif"
    _ "image/png"
    "os"

    "github.com/xyproto/palgen"
)

func main() {
    g := new(gif.GIF)
    g.Image = make([]*image.Paletted, 1)
    g.Delay = make([]int, 1)

    f, err := os.Open("source.png")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    img, _, err := image.Decode(f)
    pal, err := palgen.Generate(img, 256)

    Paletted := image.NewPaletted(img.Bounds(), pal)
    draw.FloydSteinberg.Draw(Paletted, img.Bounds(), img, image.Point{})
    g.Image[0] = Paletted
    g.Delay[0] = 100

    out, err := os.Create("gif.gif")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    err = gif.EncodeAll(out, g)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Source image `source.png`:

[image: source.png]

Final GIF `gif.gif`:

[image: gif.gif]

Comment: I tried it again using your method, but there are still some black spots around the edges of the GIF

Comment: I added the result to the problem description

Comment: You still don't give the original png's. You don't give the fully working code you use. You show another obviously combined image for which you don't show the code how it was created. As I demonstrated using your combined png by cutting out the top image, it works sufficiently well for Go 1.19 and the single example image. How do you expect people to help you when you're not giving enough information?

Comment: Sorry,I just think this is a general problem that doesn't depend on my original drawing.Now I attach my original png.Help me again ,Thanks

Comment: `palgen` will not help if you have many colors like [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/CIE1931xy_blank.svg/300px-CIE1931xy_blank.svg.png). However, downscaling the result may help, dithering will look pretty nice.

Comment: @Jishi have you found a solution? Try to add `image.Transparent`, `image.White`, `image.Black` to palette after `palgen.Generate(img, 253)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`draw.Draw(Paletted,img.Bounds(),img,image.ZP, draw.Src)`

Replace:
`draw.FloydSteinberg.Draw(Paletted, img.Bounds(), img, image.Point{})`